# cygstart doesn't start a process with a domain user

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I installed Cygwin 1.7 on a remote machine and I am able to connect with the default user "cyg_server" and start a process via `cygstart`.

I would like to do exactly the same thing but with a different user. I created it in this way: 
`mkpasswd -d DOMAIN -p /home -u USER >>/etc/passwd`

I can connect smoothly, but when I use `cygstart` to run my target process nothing happen. From the console I don't get any message at all, but I am sure of that because after I launch `taskkill` to check the existence of the process.

Finally, if I connect remotely to my machine and I run the same command directly in the cygwin console I don't have any problem.

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to accomplish that.

First of all, it is necessary assign the following privileges to the user:

- `editrights -l -u USER`
- `editrights -a SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege -u USER`
- `editrights -a SeCreateTokenPrivilege -u USER`
- `editrights -a SeTcbPrivilege -u USER`
- `editrights -a SeServiceLogonRight -u USER`
- `editrights -l -u USER`

After, I restarted my machine (perhaps it is not essential) and I run my command with the action runas:
`cygstart --action=runas COMMAND`

I hope it helps.